# easy way to assign function onclick - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, assign

I am searching for much time now, for a very simple and effective way to aasign function on the click of a button in javascript (not jQuery).

The problems that I have are : 1.sometimes the dom is not yet created and the javascript function has undefined vars in it. 2.I can't pass in the right way attributes to this function.

So baically i have these:

```
<div class="container">
    <button type=button class="click">Click</button>

    <div class="smallContainer">
        <img src="source.com" class="myimage">
        <div class="data"> some data</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <button type=button class="click">Click</button>

    <div class="smallContainer">
        <img src="source.com" class="myimage">
        <div class="data"> other data</div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <button type=button class="click">Click</button>

    <div class="smallContainer">
        <img src="source.com" class="myimage">
        <div class="data"> usefull data</div>
    </div>
</div>


for (){ assign in each button the onclick function}

function onclick(){
        here i want to change the opacity of the image by the class "myimage",
        take the innerHTML of the div by the class "data" and do something to it(maybe i ll send an ajax request in this function also)
    }
```

So I need a for loop or something (inside the javascript file maybe), that will asign to all buttons this function. I need every time I click the button, the function to know which button is and what the div by the class "data" has inside.

I tried many ways, each one had problems. Can anyone help with a simple working solution?

Thank you

Comment: If you use jQuery or another library you will make your job easier. Is there something that stops you from using a js library?

Comment: For this, jQuery is the obvious choice. $function() { $(".click").on("click", function() { $(this).whateveryouwant... }); }); if you add Ajax to the mix, then there is almost no discussion

Comment: the only thing that stops me, is that i have a deadline very soon and that i know javascript basics but no jQuery or other library at all. And I have to do much stuff inside the function.

Comment: @Vlenorroia, if you have more tasks related to DOM manipulation, learning jQuery or another library will save you a lot of time. And learning them is quite easy. Just follow the samples. The other option is to write some simple library for yourself but this will require some time and effort. If you choose the latter then this site will be your best friend http://www.quirksmode.org/. Check the compatibility tables to see what the browsers support and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you do not have the skills to do this simple in plain JavaScript, then it is time to get jQuery added to your toolbox.

Here is about all the code you would need

```
 $function() { // when the page is ready
   $(".click").on("click", function(e) { // assign a function to ALL class="click" 
     var id = this.id; // or $(this).attr("id"); - if you need the button's ID
     var divContent = $(this).parents().find(".data").html()
     $.get("someserver.php",{"id":id,"parm":divContent},function(data) {
       alert(data);//  from server
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: ok i think i understand this, but what is the last function(data) ? what does it do and what is data attribute?

Comment: The data is passed to the function(data) from the server call. It is whatever your server sends when called with the parameters

Answer (score -2):

try using jquery library :) with that yoy can do codes like

```
<script>
$(".data").click(function(){
  var class_value = $(this).html();
})
</script>
```

as you can see, the function will be applied to all element having tha class "data"

Comment: because i want inside the function that is called, to do many stuff to the div which has the button, i prefer javascript because i know some basics and jQuery i don't know it t all :)

Comment: Poor example since .val() is for input and click is the name of his class